# Is it possible to update list of objects except the MIN value in this list in one LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

I think my question is from functional programming.
By the way I wrote some code for updating list of my objects:

```
var minDate = userRecords.Min(x => x.FromDate);
return userRecords.Where(x => x.FromDate != minDate).Select(x =>
    {
        x.IsInitialRecord = false;
        return x;
    });
```

I want to rewrite it without using local variable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple question, Why ? It's probably doable but that also means recalculating that same min over and over for each item in the list

Comment: Dont' have an IDE here atm, could you try: `return userRecords.Where(x => x.FromDate != userRecords.Min(y => y.FromDate)).Select(x =>
    {
        x.IsInitialRecord = false;
        return x;
    });`

Comment: @Max Yep, it is a possible solution but unfortunately I have `SkipWhile` invocation to apply request filter before I need to exclude min value by date and update other elements.

Comment: Reading the description of the used tag: *Functional programming is a programming paradigm based upon building abstractions using functions, avoiding side effects and change of state.*. And what we see in your code - using side effects of the `Select`, mutating state... And btw, in order to "update list of your objects", someone has to `foreach` the result of your method, which also is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ivan's comment that mutating state in that context is prone to end up in code smell.

But if one would insist to go that road, I'd at least try to encapsulate the state mutation, as in e.g.,

(contrived)

```
    public class UserRecord
    {
        public UserRecord(DateTime fromDate)
        {
            FromDate = fromDate;
            AfterUpdate(true);
        }

        public UserRecord AfterUpdate(bool initialRecord)
        {
            IsInitialRecord = initialRecord;
            return this;
        }

        public DateTime FromDate { get; private set; }
        public bool IsInitialRecord { get; private set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userRecords =
            new[]
            {
                new UserRecord(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)),
                new UserRecord(new DateTime(1801, 1, 1)),
                new UserRecord(new DateTime(1913, 1, 1)),
                new UserRecord(new DateTime(1850, 1, 1))
            };

        var updatedRecords =
            (
                from minDate in new[] { userRecords.Min(r => r.FromDate) }
                from record in userRecords
                where record.FromDate > minDate
                select record.AfterUpdate(false)
            );

        foreach (var record in updatedRecords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", record.FromDate, record.IsInitialRecord);
        }

        // Etc...
    }
```

'HTH,